# How to power a low voltage LED with a high voltage source?

Tags: led, dc, low-power

I have a panel-mount LED (https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=A-LED8-1GAAS-PR7-1) that is described as "2.2V 30mA" and I would like to power it with a 28V DC source. My questions are as follows:

1) Would I be better off to find a 28V rated LED such as https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/dialight/24979723732504F/350-2400-ND/2428891

or

2) What kind of circuitry would I require to power the 2.2V 30mA LED with the 28V DC source?

Additionally, the first scenario would be quick and easy, but which scenario would be better in terms of power consumption?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need the LED for? Do you need it to have all 5000 mcd shining light, or you need it for an indication that the 28 V is there?

Comment: Maybe you want it to go on only when the Voltage is above 24V?

Comment: According to the data sheet the operating voltage is 4 volts.

Comment: Both are about the same price.  Go with the one with the resistor built in.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to put a resistor from the 28V in series with the LED unit. The LED drops 2.2V at 30mA. So this added resistor needs to drop (28 - 2.2V) = 25.8V.

A further calculation needs to be made based upon the current you want through the LED. Lets say you want it really bright so choose the full 30mA rating of the LED. Ohms law tells us that the resistor value (R) will be 25.8V / 0.030A = 860 ohms. You could pick a standard value resistor like 910 ohms or even 1K ohms but the current through the LED will be slightly less. The 1K ohm resistor would result in about 25.8mA through the LED. This current level is still probably way more than you need for a panel indicator. Even 10mA is often more than needed. So a resistor with a 3.3K standard value would allow a current of 7.6mA. This size resistor has a nice advantage in that it would only need to be a 1/4 watt rating instead of the other smaller values that would need to have much higher wattage rating.

Using the 28V rated LED unit is just going to be an indicator with an already integrated resistor inside that does the same thing as if you add one yourself.

Comment: You also have to consider the power disspated in the resistor.  My calculator says you'll need a 0.8 Watt resistor for 30 mA through the LED.

Comment: And, not mentioned by anybody so far, 30 mA is probably an absolute maximum current limit. Running at 20 mA would be a much better idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple voltage divider to power the 2.2V LED.  I used a couple of online calculators you can find with searches "Ohm's Law Calculator" and "Voltage Divider Calculator".

Step 1 was to determine the effective resistance of your LED with a voltage drop of 2.2 volts at 30 mA using the Ohm's Law Calculator, as shown below.

[image: Ohms Law Calculation]

This shows your LED will represent about 73.3 ohms of load at 30 mA.

Next, I used a Voltage Divider Calculator to quickly determine what the resistor in the voltage divider needs to be to drop the voltage.

You need an 866 ohm resistor to drop the voltage by 25.8 volts so your panel LED sees the 30 mA at 2.2 volts.

[image: Voltage Divider]

In the above diagram, replace R2 with your LED and you're good to go.  The power dissipation of R1 will be 0.774 watts, using P = E * I, or Power (watts) = Voltage (25.8) times Current (.03 amps).  This means you need at least a 1 watt resistor at 866 ohms for this application (I would use 2 watts for some headroom).

**UPDATE 1**

As pointed out in comments, Digikey has a very nice LED resistor calculator. It produces similar results as the method outlined above, albeit much faster and more easily.

As others have pointed out, you can vary the resistance upward to reduce the current drain a bit, perhaps to a standard resistor value like 1K, and reduce the brightness a bit as well.

[image]

Comment: NOT the way to do the calculation. Converting the LED to some 'equivalent' resistance makes no sense at all. Us a calculator that gives you the current based on the LED Vf and the drive voltage suchas that provided by Didgikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-led-series-resistor    The solution provides both the resistor value and the power dissipated in the resistor.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me and provides a simple way to get to the correct answer.  The LED is effectively a purely resistive load, so calculating it this way is correct.  However, I agree that Digikey calculator rocks! It's a much easier way to do LED resistor calculations. Thanks for pointing that out.  My reason for pointing to the two calculators was to teach someone how to fish vs. handing them the fish :)

Comment: His calculation is totally correct

Comment: LEDs are not in any way 'equivalent' to a resistor. They have a non-linear Vf based on current flow or temperature, trying to do it this way is not teaching a newbie to analyze the problem at all.

Comment: Jack is correct, You never simulate and LED as a resistor alone rather the voltage drop to the diode from supply. So 24-2.2V=21.8V/30mA  which by the way is exceeding the normal junction temperature in this enclosure so 25mA is safer,. while there are even brighter LEDs @ 20mA if you look around for >= 10,000 mcd  Then the power dissipation for 22V*30mA = 660mW so you need at least a 1W resistor but if you followed my advice and got a 10Cd LED you could run it at 5mA with a 1/4W R. Mind you with a supply >10x the Vf of the LED, it could be modelled as a resistor but actually it is ~1.8V+12 Ohm

Comment: 73 Ohms Not!    rather a RED 5mm LED is approx 1.8V+12 Ohms ( -25%/+50% on R tolerance)

Comment: @rbraddy: My article on [Resistance of an LED](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/resistance-of-an-led/) explains Tony's point further and may help you somewhat.

Comment: your site? bravo

Comment: Interesting that mine and Michael's answers above provide the exact same results.  I get the fact that LED's have some other properties aside from pure resistance, but it doesn't materially change the voltage divider or the circuit in the end.

Comment: In science/university, the correct answer with the wrong method usually gives 0 points on your test. Please stop fooling yourself.